# « De nouveau » ou « à nouveau » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, prépositions, adverbes

Un ami après avoir raté la préparation d'un repas affirme: « je vais le refaire de nouveau. » Pour moi, c'est « de nouveau » signifie répéter la même erreur. Donc « à nouveau » est plus convenable. Je voudrais bien un éclaircissement.

Comment: Il y a un autre problème, "refaire [de/à] nouveau" est une répétition. Il faudrait dire "refaire" ou "faire [de/à] nouveau"

Comment: @Random > "refaire à nouveau" peut indiquer qu'on a déjà refait l'action une ou plusieurs fois, et qu'on s'apprête à la refaire une n-ième fois. Je pense que l'exemple ici donné ne veut pas exprimer cela et a donc une signification erronée.

Answer (score 5):

Vous avez tout à fait saisi la nuance :

- De nouveau s'emploie dans le cas d'une seconde fois.
- À nouveau, dans le cas d'une nouvelle fois (seconde) mais laisse entendre une manière différente ou sur une base différente.

L'Académie fait une distinction entre :

- de nouveau : une fois de plus,
- à nouveau : de façon complètement différente.

  ---

***Ajout*** :

- > Ce travail est manqué, il faut le faire à nouveau.

Pas de problème de français.

- > Ce travail est manqué, il faut le *re*faire à nouveau.

Plusieurs lectures possibles, pour 'exclure' la tautologie :

- Comprendre *à nouveau* comme *à neuf*, en repartant de zéro : on peut le refaire à l'identique ou d'une nouvelle façon.
- Comprendre *à nouveau* comme d'une *encore une fois*, ce qui sous-entend que c'est au moins la troisième fois, puisqu'on l'a fait, refait et que cela ne va toujours pas.
  Si l'on recommence une troisième fois, c'est que l'on n'arrive pas au résultat attendu, et donc on essaie toujours "de faire la même chose", mais en mieux à chaque fois.
- > « Ce travail est manqué, il faut *re*faire, à nouveau, la même chose ! »

... avec un temps de pose marqué à chaque virgule, pour souligner l' insistance de la demande, comme on enfonce un clou en répétant la frappe pour qu'il pénètre de plus en plus, on est dans le domaine de l'oral familier, ou de l'intention littéraire soigneusement encadré de `« ... »`.
 Sans les virgules, on reste dans le domaine du pléonasme.

Cette interprétation est très subjective et non académique :

- Donné tel quel, c'est un pléonasme.
  Il est donc déconseillé de s'en servir innocemment (surtout à l'écrit dans des documents officiels)
- *[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faire+%C3%A0+nouveau%2Crefaire+%C3%A0+nouveau&year_start=100&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfaire%20%C3%A0%20nouveau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crefaire%20%C3%A0%20nouveau%3B%2Cc0)* *Refaire à nouveau* est de moins en moins utilisé (il est dommage de de ne pas connaître comment il a été employé, et par qui), *[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faire+de+nouveau%2Crefaire+de+nouveau&year_start=100&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfaire%20de%20nouveau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crefaire%20de%20nouveau%3B%2Cc0)* *Refaire de nouveau* est très très peu usité.
- On peut signifier l'intention littéraire en encadrant soigneusement la phrase de guillemets (au format français : « ... »  ) et en s'assurant de sa ponctuation.

---

<sup>- [*Références trouvées ici*](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic6317-a-nouveau-et-de-nouveau.html).
 - Comme le note @random dans son commentaire, il faut faire attention au contexte de la phrase pour éviter la redondance (la tautologie, le pléonasme).</sup>

Comment: With the French corpus, [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faire+%C3%A0+nouveau%2Crefaire+%C3%A0+nouveau&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfaire%20%C3%A0%20nouveau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crefaire%20%C3%A0%20nouveau%3B%2Cc0) finds some _refaire à nouveau_

Comment: @VincentG -- Merci, j'ai amendé ma réponse... très souvent je me fait avoir par le corpus par défaut !